# Not completed CSV/Treads during data driven testing

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

I have using CSV file(with 5 users)and i have been given 5 in plan thread...It supposed to be completed with 5 user thread success, instead of this i receiving only 4 threads results(with pass).

Can anyone?[image]

[image]

Comment: Did the assertion failed on the 4th one maybe?

Comment: No, I made all the credentials (5 threads/credentials) now as right.But still i could see only 4 passed threads

Comment: Have you tried running the test w/out Response Assertion? Do you still get 4 results?

Comment: am getting response data like as below,

Comment: <section id="main-wrapper" class="theme-default" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        <!-- Page wrapper -->
        <header id="header" ng-include="'views/layout/header.html'">

Comment: <!-- Left Sidebar Navigation -->
        <aside class="sidebar sidebar-left" ng-include="'views/layout/left-sidebar.html'" ></aside>
        <!-- Content wraper -->
        <section class="main-content-wrapper">

Comment: <!-- Main content view  -->
            <div ui-view></div>
            
            <!-- Footer -->
            <div ng-include="'views/layout/footer.html'"></div>
        </section>
        <!-- /Content wraper-->
    </section>

Comment: Yes, However right or wrong only 4 results displaying, even I tried with application's "Text" or above "tags" in the assertion.

Comment: But in the thread i have given 5 and CSV 5 as well.

Comment: And you are sure .csv is good? Even it should not have effect on this issue...

Comment: Could you please set Recycle on EOF > true and Stop thread on EOF > false in a CSV Data Set Config and then try again?

Comment: Great Ivan!!!  Now it is working....how it is possible?....can you explain bit more about the config setting.....it would be nice to me to ahead....

Comment: I would guess your CSV has only 4 valid lines. With these settings, JMeter will read csv again from top if there are more threads than valid entries in CSV file. Settings you had were the opposite... :-)

Comment: 1.Allow quoted data, 2.Recycle on EOF, 3.Stop shared on EOF, 4.Sharing modes...could you please explain these configs in a simple word

Comment: I will put everything as an answer mate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the CSV Data Set Config component settings. For your CSV you should have these settings:

> Recycle on EOF = true
>
> Stop thread on EOF = false

I guess your CSV data doesn't have 5 valid entries, so with these settings it will run as many threads as you set it. **You should inspect** your CSV if entries used in your test are important and relevant for test results.

About these settings:

- **Allow quoted data** - Should the CSV file allow values to be quoted? If enabled, then values can be enclosed in " - double-quote - allowing values to contain a delimiter.
- **Recycle on EOF?** - Should the file be re-read from the beginning on reaching EOF? (default is true).
- **Stop thread on EOF?** - Should the thread be stopped on EOF, if Recycle is false? (default is false).
- **Sharing mode** :

  - *All threads* - (the default) the file is shared between all the threads.
  - *Current thread group* - each file is opened once for each thread group in which the element appears.
  - *Current thread* - each file is opened separately for each thread.
  - *Identifier* - all threads sharing the same identifier share the same file. So for example if you have 4 thread groups, you could use a common id for two or more of the groups to share the file between them. Or you could use the thread number to share the file between the same thread numbers in different thread groups.

This is from the **Apache JMeter** [website](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).