# Concurrent users for each CSV record in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

My test plan looks as below

```
Testplan (Users,AppURL,Port,Ramp_Up,Iteration)
    Thread group
        CSV (Path,Method,LoopCount)(Recycle EOF = False, Stop Thread EOF = False, Sharing mode = All Threads)
            User Param (initialized Iteration to LoopCount)
            LoopController (passing Iteration User Param)
                IF (POST)
                    HTTP Request
```

My csv has 12 lines, I am running in non-gui mode, by passing threads as 20.
However during execution only 12 threads are used, I would like to use all 20 to be active.
I set Recycle EOF = true, but it loops way beyond the defined loop count set in my csv. 
Kindly suggest a solution

Comment: What is the configuration in the `Thread Group`

Comment: I am reading Threads and Ramp-up via command line -J switch. These variables are added at TestPlan level, Loop Count I left it as 1, since I am using Loop Controller inside..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want 20 users to run from 12 csv values. If so have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607445/not-completed-csv-treads-during-data-driven-testing/38612806#38612806). It should help you.

Comment: I Tried the option, but the problem is I am not sure which among the 12 threads are consuming the extra 8. As a result, the results are kind of skewed. (Further, my csv has the loop count set for each of the csv rows, which I am consuming in the loop controller, so if I use the suggested appraoch, it was getting tough understanding the execution results)

Comment: As I know, those 8 extras should be first 8 from the top.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Ivan, the case I am looking is 20 concurrent threads, burning down all of 12 records, per their individual loop counter,defined in csv. The case you mentioned, it is re-execution of records 1-8 of csv.